# How to "control" when Firestore.getAll(...promises) stops by reject

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Context:**

I 'm doing a cloud function to send pushes to multiple users. I need to recover the info of each user to know some data like, name, country..etc..

**Problem:**

Actually I recover the list of user Id's and when I got it, then I create an array of `promises`to recover all the info:

```
var usersPromises = []
for (var i = 0; i < usersInRange.length; i++) {
   usersPromises[i] = firestore.collection("users").doc(usersInRange[i])
}
```

Then I recover and send the push using `firestore.getAll()`:

```
firestore.getAll(...usersPromises).then(results => {
   for(snapshot in results){
      if(snapshot.exists){
         ......
         var user = snapshot.data()
         ......
      }else{
         ......
      }
   }
})
```

This `solution` is actually working "fine" almost all the time. But at this moment the Firestore db has some users that do not exist or something is wrong, because the method `getAll()`stops before finishing all the promises. I know it because no push is sent, and in the console, just say that the method has finished.

Reading in SO and documentation, I saw, that getAll stops if some promise is "broken". (all or nothing)

And here is where I'm lost. How can I "force" or do in another way, to just "jump" this promises that can't be completed?

*P.S:*

I tried to do with a "for" but It seems to omit some promises:

```
for (var i = 0; i < usersPromises.length; i++) {
   usersPromises[i]
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.exists){
           ......
           var user = snapshot.data()
           ......
        }else{
           ......
        }
      })
}
```

Comment: You mention "something is wrong, because the method getAll() **stops before finishing all the promises**" Can you share the code of your entire Cloud Function, because it may be caused by another problem (promises not returned). BTW, note that what you pass to `getAll` is not Promises but `DocumentReference`s or `ReadOptions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its not a problem of `getAll`. I have tested like this:

```
const firestore = new Firestore();

let doc = []
doc[0] = firestore.doc('test/test');
doc[1] = firestore.doc('test/test1');
doc[2] = firestore.doc('test/doc');

firestore.getAll(...doc)
.then(result=> result.forEach(doc => console.log(doc._fieldsProto)))
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

In my database I have 'test/test' and 'test/doc' document, but I do not have  'test/test1' and results look like this:

[image]

So we just get `undefined` on document that is not exist and that's all. I suggest to add `catch` and see if there is any exception. When I have been writing the test the function was interrupted by typo mistake in inner function.

I hope this will help!